# Transform an object into an array of single key/value objects

Tags: javascript

I have this variable:

```
let json1 = 
{'aaa': {'cus1':1,'cus2':2},
 'bbb': {'cus3':1,'cus4':5}
}
```

And I would like to convert it into the following array:

```
[{'aaa': {'cus1':1,'cus2':2}},
 {'bbb': {'cus3':1,'cus4':5}}
]
```

What I tried to do is:

```
let arr = [];
let keys = Object.keys(json1);
keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc.push({key: json1[key]});
        return acc;
    }, arr);
```

While I get:

```
[ { key: { cus1: 1, cus2: 2 } }, { key: { cus3: 1, cus4: 5 } } ]
```

So evidently I would like to use the true key instead of `key` as the key of my encapsulated json in the arr.

P.S. Is there any way to do this **without using for loop**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```js
acc.push({key: json1[key]});
//        ^
//        here
```

In this context `key` is literally the name of the property. However what you are looking for is to evaluate `key` as the name of your property (aka [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)):

```js
acc.push({[key]: json1[key]});
//        ^
//        now your property name is whatever `key` value is
```

A simple example:

```js
var key = '';
var obj = {[key]: true};

obj;
//=> { "": true }
```

Now to answer your question:

```js
const split =
  obj =>
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) =>
        ({[k]: v}));

split({ aaa: {cus1: 1, cus2: 2}
      , bbb: {cus3: 1, cus4: 5}
      });

//=> [ { aaa: {cus1: 1, cus2: 2} }
//=> , { bbb: {cus3: 1, cus4: 5} }
//=> ]
```

Comment: The image in the answer is unnecessary imo, and could be replace with one additional line `obj; //=> { "": true }` in the code block above it.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Sure. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the separated key/value pair to a new object with the given key.

```js
const
    data = { aaa: { cus1: 1, cus2: 2 }, bbb: { cus3: 1, cus4: 5 } },
    array = Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));
    
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```